# Different values for distortion coefficients from calibrateCamera and stereoCalibrate

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to calibrate a stereo pair of web cams using chessboard. For this I have fixed the relative positions of 2 cameras and made a photo of a chessboard so that the `findChessboardCorners` function detects the corners on both images - 'left.png' and 'right.png'. My code looks as follows:

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)
 lf = 'left.png'
 rf = 'right.png'
 lim = cv2.imread(lf, 0)
 rim = cv2.imread(rf, 0)

 nrows = 9
 ncols = 6

 objp = np.zeros((nrows * ncols, 3), np.float32)
 objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:nrows, 0:ncols].T.reshape(-1, 2)
 objpoints=[objp]


 lret, lcorners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(limg, (nrows, ncols), None)
 rret, rcorners =.findChessboardCorners(rimg, (nrows, ncols), None)

 cv2.cornerSubPix(limg, lcorners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
 cv2.cornerSubPix(rimg, rcorners, (11, 11), (-1, -1), criteria)
 limgpoints = [lcorners]
 rimgpoints = [rcorners]

 retval, cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R, T, E, F = cv2.stereoCalibrate(objpoints,limgpoints, rimgpoints, None, None,None,None, limg.shape[::-1],flags = cv2.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL ,criteria=criteria)

 ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, limgpoints, limg.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

I would expect that the arrays dist and ditsCoeffs1 coincide, since thay are intristic parameters of the left camera. However the values in distCoeffs1 are of the order `e-1 - e+1`, while the values of dist ~ `e-0 - e-2`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The target pose(s) and camera parameters are optimized jointly in both cases, but the optimization problems are different, so the cost functions are different, so it's not surprising that the solvers find different solutions.

However you should expect that the two solutions be close. The reason they aren't in your case is likely because you are calibrating on one target image only. You should use more data to better constrain the solution.

Comment: Thanks, Francesco, but I think that 54 points are enough in order to get at least similar orders of magnitude. I suspect I messed the flags parameter in the `cv2.stereoCalibrate`.

Comment: By "more" data I meant more images, spanning multiple poses.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was trivial - the flags parameter should be set to 0 for the stereoCalibrate function.